# .htaccess deny from all

Tags: .htaccess

I have copied one of my old applications and renamed it to `New_application`. I want to access `.htaccess` file that is inside the `New_application` folder. When I opened it with my text editor, it just showed `Deny from all`. I tried to open `.htaccess` in my old application, it showed `Deny from all` too. I remember I was able to edit it before but not sure what I can't now. Any thoughts? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 191, accepted):

```
Deny from all
```

is an .htaccess command (the actual content of that file you are trying to view). Not a denial of being able to edit the file. Just reopen the `.htaccess` file in the text viewer of choice and make the alterations as you so desire, save it, then reupload it to your folder of choice.

Though I think inadvertently you are blocking even yourself from viewing said application once uploaded.

I would do something like:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

which will deny everyone but the IP in the `allow from` line, which you would change the IP to match your IP which you can obtain from http://www.whatismyip.com/ or similar site.

Comment: Goes without saying, but be wary of shared IP addresses!

Comment: `order deny, allow` should be `order deny,allow` (no space after `,`) otherwise some Apache versions will show Server Error because `order takes one argument, 'allow,deny', 'deny,allow'` (Says Apache Log)

Comment: for windows users , make sure you make the file name exactly `.htaccess` by save-as the file from some text editor because windows explorer doesn't allow you to remove file names. it was a problem for me

Comment: Well, windows does allow you to, but you have to go about doing so in a roundabout way.  Such as through the terminal (or CMD), you can also choose to show all files hidden and otherwise, as well as show file extensions from which you can make a .htaccess.txt that you can then remove the .txt from later since your showing the extensions. Also since your showing hidden files you can select and delete the file in explorer. Then as I said you can do it in the command line too. So its not impossible but windows does like to make it difficult sometimes.

Answer (score 30):

This syntax has changed with the newer Apache HTTPd server, please see [upgrade to apache 2.4 doc](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html) for full details.

2.2 configuration syntax was

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

2.4 configuration now is

```
Require all denied
```

Thus, this 2.2 syntax

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

Would ne now written

```
Require local
```

Answer (score 4):

You can edit it. The content of the file is literally "Deny from all" which is an Apache directive: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny

Answer (score 0):

A little alternative to [@gasp´s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2829210/gasp) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41673930/3680335) is to simply put the ***actual domain name*** you are running it from. Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html

> In the following example, there is no authentication and all hosts in
> the example.org domain are allowed access; all other hosts are denied
> access.

Apache 2.2 configuration:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from example.org
```

Apache 2.4 configuration:

```
Require host example.org
```