# Disallow direct access to subfolder from external IP Addres

Tags: apache

In the process of moving an application from ColdFusion to PHP, I have a ColdFusion server running on CentoOS using apache. Despite a correct robots.txt disallowing the indexing of my application it has come attention that some files from the clients were indexed.

I need to know how to set up apache to only allow access to file from the server itself and NOT allow anyone to access the files from the inter-google. SO if you were to click the link it would deny access, but if you were to attempt to download it from the application itself (using a download script) it would allow it to download. Is it possible and how?

LOVE that the search engine ignored my robots.txt. Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) What research have you done? [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507645/htaccess-deny-from-all)

Comment: `<Directory /var/www/html/mywebsite/file/file/files>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from *Server IP Address*
 </Directory>`

Comment: Do I have to put each directory or lets say I have a path that is mysite.com/users/information/files and I only put '/users' will it also block everyone from the folders inside?

Comment: you could always use an `.htaccess` file at the root of where you wish to block with the line `deny from all`. Your download script should then send the file as an attachment (assuming script and file are local to each other)

Comment: Will .htaccess work with a ColdFusion server?

Comment: `.htaccess` is an apache thing. So if apache is handling the requests, it should work