# 403 Permission error on Ajax Call in Yii?

Tags: php, jquery, yii, permissions

I am new to Yii. I have created a module which has below codes:

Controller's Code:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete','ajaxdialog'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

AND here is action i want to use by ajax call:

```
public function actionAjaxdialog()
{
    $user_id =  $_POST['image_id'];     
    $is_active = $_POST['status'];
    $model = $this->loadModel($image_id);
    $model->is_active = $is_active;
    $model->update();   
}
```

view's code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.changeStatus').live('click',function(){
    var status = $(this).attr('status');
    if(status==1)
    {
        status=0;
    }
    else
    {
        status=1;
    }
    var id = $(this).attr('image_id');      
    var $link = $(this);

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:    "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('Gallery/Ajaxdialog'); ?>",
        data:  {image_id:id,status:status},
        success: function(msg)
        {   
            if(status==0)
            {
                $link.attr('status','0');
                $link.attr('title','In-active :: click to activate.');
                $link.children('img').attr('src','/images/wrong.png');
                AfterStatusChange('Image has been de-activated sucessfully.');
                $link.parent().parent().removeClass('selected');
            }
            else
            {
                $link.attr('status','1');
                $link.attr('title','Active :: click to de-activate.');
                $link.children('img').attr('src','/images/right.png');
                AfterStatusChange('Image has been activated sucessfully.');
                $link.parent().parent().removeClass('selected');
            }


        },
        error: function(xhr){
            //alert("failure"+xhr.readyState+this.url)
            alert("failure"+xhr.responseText);
        }
    });


});
});
```

I am working on **localhost**, i have update "**.htaccess**" file with following code:

```
deny from all
Allow from localhost
```

It always gives me the following error when i tries to run it:

"Access forbidden"

Please help me how can i resolve this issue.

Comment: So you have apache or yii forbidden error? Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507645/htaccess-deny-from-all

Comment: Can you use action `admin` or action `delete`?

Comment: @Pitchinnate that is inbuilt i am using(for delete).

Comment: I know but do you get a `access forbidden` on those also?

Comment: @Pitchinnate no.its working fine.

Comment: If you remove the `deny from all` in your `.htaccess` does it run correctly?

Comment: @Pitchinnate it not working.

Comment: If you look at the HTML source code what is the result of:
`url:    "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('Gallery/Ajaxdialog'); ?>",`

Comment: it gives me /gigolez/index.php?r=Gallery/Ajaxdialog

Comment: <?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('gallery/ajaxdialog'); ?>
Make the first letter for controllerId and actionId in lower case. and tell me what it does, and instead of localhost in htaccess use 127.0.0.1

Comment: where's "order deny,allow" in ur htaccess?

Comment: @CherifBOUCHELAGHEM order deny,allow
allow from 127.0.0.1

Comment: you say modules so the url must be /module/controller/action may be you point to another controller can you check?

Comment: @CherifBOUCHELAGHEM i not using module.i was just saying i m working on module but in real scenario.

Comment: Any news? I tried to reproduce this but it works fine for me!! weired

Comment: `$model = $this->loadModel($image_id);` `$image_id` -what that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix the forbidden issue with the following Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    url      : "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('test/ajax');?>",
    data     : {},
    type     : "POST",
    dataType : "html",
    success  : function(response){
        $('#test').html(response);
    },
    error    : function(){
        alert("Failed request data from AJAX request");
    }
});
```

On the controller:

```
public function accessRules() {
    return array(
        array(
            'allow',
            'actions' => array('ajax'),
            'users'   => array('@'),
        ),
    );
}
```

You may try with this one.

Comment: This does not work all the time

Answer (score 0):

add the csrfToken in ajax data.

```
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:    "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('Gallery/Ajaxdialog'); ?>",
        data:  {<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfParam; ?> : '<?= Yii::$app->request->csrfToken; ?>',image_id:id,status:status},
        success: function(msg)
        {   
            if(status==0)
            {
                $link.attr('status','0');
                $link.attr('title','In-active :: click to activate.');
                $link.children('img').attr('src','/images/wrong.png');
                AfterStatusChange('Image has been de-activated sucessfully.');
                $link.parent().parent().removeClass('selected');
            }
            else
            {
                $link.attr('status','1');
                $link.attr('title','Active :: click to de-activate.');
                $link.children('img').attr('src','/images/right.png');
                AfterStatusChange('Image has been activated sucessfully.');
                $link.parent().parent().removeClass('selected');
            }


        },
        error: function(xhr){
            //alert("failure"+xhr.readyState+this.url)
            alert("failure"+xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
```