# Php file permission

Tags: php, mysql, file, permissions, download

I already read a lot of posts about it but I somehow I cant figure it out. 
I would like to: 
1. Store files on a server (upload), they path is stored in a mysql-db 
2. Give them back for download using php 
3. If someone knows the path on the server they shouldnt be able to open it.
1 and 2 are already working, but 3 is giving me headache. If I change the permission so nobody can open it, the php-user cant open it either. 
I am looking for a hidden from the public folder that the php can access. I also tried to set the php-user as the owner of the folder and restriced read-permission for public but that didnt work, too.

Cheers :)

Comment: Grant 755 as permission to the upload folder ? 
http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/new-user-tutorial-basic-file-permissions/

Comment: Store the files outside the documentroot or disallow access: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507645/htaccess-deny-from-all

Answer (score 0):

You could create in the folder an .htaccess file with the following content:

```
Deny  From All
```